# calculate time difference in minutes of multiple rows based on date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to calculate time difference based on date .

My table is jobTable

```
jobid   Date        job_started                |    
---------------------------------------------
1       03-08-2020  03-08-2020 00:01:01     |
1       03-08-2020  03-08-2020 00:01:02     |
1       03-08-2020  03-08-2020 00:01:04     |
1       03-08-2020  03-08-2020 00:01:10     |
1       03-08-2020  03-08-2020 00:01:30     |
1       03-08-2020  04-08-2020 00:01:01     |
---------------------------------------------
```

I need time difference of job id 1 on the date 03-08-2020 in seconds as 33

I have tried this query

```
select to_seconds((
  select t2.job_started
  from JobTable t2
  where t2.job_started > t1.job_started
    and date(t2.job_started) <= '03-08-2020'
  order by t2.job_started asc
  limit 1
)) - to_seconds(t1.job_started) as interval_seconds
from JobTable t1
where date(t1.job_started) >= '03-08-2020'
  and date(t1.job_started) < '04-08-2020'
  and t1.job_started <> (
    select job_started
    from JobTable
    where date(job_started) <= '04-08-2020'
    order by job_started desc
    limit 1
  )
;
```

I am getting all interval seconds as 1 2 4 6 20
but I need an overall interval as 33 i.e half minute.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would help us understand your requirement if you added sample data from more dates and more distinct jobid values. Please [edit] your question to add more sample data and a sample of the result you need.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you want exactly from the table and where 1 2 4 6 20 come from?

Comment: those are time intervals between two rows. i.e 1second, 2 second,4 second i need overall interval of that job performed i.e 33 seconds.